# WebRTC - enable sound in chrome doesn't work

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

I need to create mute/unmute sound in my app using WebRTC.

I created a function:

```
this.StreamSound = function(aStream)
{
    mStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = aStream
}
```

It works in FF but in chrome don't (aStream == false) :/
Any idea?

(I'm testing it by local "video" tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a local stream, to mute on a local video, you should set the 'muted' property on the local video tag.

If using jQuery the code will be:

```
$('#localvideo').prop('muted',true);
```

For muting audio that is being sent on the PeerConnection to a remote browser the audio tracks enabled should work in both Firefox and Chrome.